# how to make a sounds database in android application programming?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, audio

i am currently working in making an offline android translator search engine (but only words). my plan is to create a table (in SQLite) containing the list of words that can be searched in my app, display its translation (in the target language) and display a button to be clicked by the user if he wants to hear how to speak the word in that particular language. the sounds database (which will contains the sounds of words in a certain dialect) will be contained in a separate database (and will referenced to the _id of the word that is type on my textbox as a foreign key)

my problem is that when i try finding in the net how to make a database for sounds in android programming, i only got MediaPlayer() and soundPool() functions, just functions how to play a music file (in the background or sound effects.)

my questions is:

1. is it possible to use the SQLite to store sounds in database? or if not, what possible solutions or database softwares can i used to make one?

hope someone could help me. :)

thanks in advance

Comment: storing sounds in database is not good idea(probably not possible). store path of sound files in sqlite or TextToSpeech may become alternative.

Comment: maybe ill take the first one, storing path of sound files (in SQLite) that maybe stored in the res/raw folder (the sounds itself).

using texttospeech may be impossible because the language i am preferring is a dialect and only spoken in a small town or village/ just for a limited people.

Answer (score 0):

Store the sound files as `blob` in database.

But still it would not be a good idea to store that in database. You could download the sounds from your server once the application is run for the first time and save in your device storage and reference those sounds' path in your local database.